# Where to find the unresolved identifier ‘Devider' in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am still pretty new to iOS. So today I created a dummy project. Actually it is a single view project followed the guide and choose the default "SwiftUI" option.

It creates a `ContentView.swift` like the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
// The rest is for preview
```

Now I just want to add a `Devider` and then another line of text, followed by some tutorial from Internet.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        Devider()
        Text("This is an App.")
    }
}
```

But in the line `Devider()` it shows an error message "Use of unresolved identifier 'Devider'".

Where can I find this class? The tutorial seems to assume it is implied by `import SwiftUI`.

I am using XCode v11.4.1 (11E503a).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed typo

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        Divider()              // << here !!
        Text("This is an App.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch... that hurts. But I mean I need to resolve the error message.

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic. There is a  dedicated  “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo” closing reason.

Comment: Technically the title is correct - the scope of "where" is the Apple libraries, not the code. I can try to add 100 words to make it more precise but I assume normal people will understand.